# Nginx gives an Internal Server Error 500 after I have configured basic auth

Tags: nginx

I am trying to do basic auth on Nginx. I have version 1.9.3 up and running on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine with a simple html file.

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  "Some shoddy text"
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.1.30;
        location / {
            root /www;
            index index.html;
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/users;
        }
    }
}
```

I used htpasswd to create two users in the "users" file under /etc (username "calvin" password "Calvin", and username "hobbes" password "Hobbes"). It's encrypted by looks like this:

```
calvin:$apr1$Q8LGMfGw$RbO.cG4R1riIfERU/175q0
hobbes:$apr1$M9KoUUhh$ayGd8bqqlN989ghWdTP4r/
```

All files belong to root:root. The server IP address is 192.168.1.30 and I am referencing that directly in the conf file.

It all works fine if I comment out the two auth lines and restart nginx, but if I uncomment them, then I do indeed get the username and password prompts when I try to load the site, but immediately thereafter get an Error 500 Internal Server error which seems to persist and I have to restart nginx.

Anybody can see what I'm doing wrong here? I had the same behaviour on the standard Ubuntu 14.04 apt-get version of Nginx (1.4.something) so I don't think it's the nginx version.

Answer (score 62):

Not really an answer to your question as you are using MD5. However as this thread pops up when searching for the error, I am attaching this to it.

Similar errors happen when `bcrypt` is used to generate passwords for `auth_basic`:

```
htpasswd -B <file> <user> <pass>
```

Since `bcrypt` is not supported within `auth_basic` ATM, mysterious 500 errors can be found in nginx error.log, (usually found at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`), they look something like this:

`*1 crypt_r() failed (22: Invalid argument), ...`

At present the solution is to generate a new password using md5, which is the default anyway.

#### Edited to address md5 issues as brought up by @EricWolf in the comments:

**md5** has its problems for sure, some context can be found in the following threads

- [Is md5 considered insecure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)
- [Is md5 still considered secure for single use authentications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756697/is-md5-still-considered-secure-for-single-use-authentications)

Of the two, speed issue can be mitigated by using [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), by banning on failed basic auth you'll make online brute forcing impractical ([guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04)). You can also use long passwords to try and fortify a bit as suggested [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46883/is-every-hash-format-that-nginx-accepts-for-http-basic-auth-weak-against-brute-f).

Other than that it seems this is as good as it gets with nginx...

Comment: OP's htpasswd file contains `$apr1$` which is Apache's MD5. If they were using bcrypt, it would contain `$2y$`. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html.

Comment: This is a valuable answer. Had the problem. Not using bcrypt for basic auth solved the issue.

Comment: Super happy it helped :) !

Comment: Isn't md5 insecure though?

Comment: This answer isn't quite right. nginx defers support to crypt_r, which is a part of libc. If the version of libc shipped with the operating system doesn't have bcrypt support, then you will see this error message.

Comment: @stevvooe, interesting, I would expect password generation to fail as well than, or is `htpasswd` using something else. Also I don't see `bcrypt` mentioned in the [docs]:  (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html). Could you maybe link to the source, I'd really like to update the answer to be correct

Comment: @DrazenUrch This is exactly what the error message is saying. `crypt_r` is a libc function. [This](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/29) is directly from the nginx developers. I am unfamiliar with the code base of htpasswd, but it is safe to assume it using something else, likely provided by apr.

Comment: md5 is really not a good idea but luckily nginx supports anything the libraries do, so you can use sha-512 (`mkpasswd -m sha-512`) as a secure alternative of not-supported bcrypt, scrypt or else.

Comment: I had the same error behavior but on my end the issue was that the rights on the .htpasswd were wrong (file was belonging to another user than the one running nginx process)

Answer (score 15):

I had goofed up when initially creating a user.  As a result, the htpasswd file looked like:

```
user:
user:$apr1$passwdhashpasswdhashpasswdhash...
```

After deleting the blank user, everything worked fine.

Comment: I had exactly same problem! I wish the error msg was more descriptive.

Answer (score 6):

I was running Nginx in a Docker environment and I had the same issue. The reason was that some of the passwords were generated using bcrypt. I resolved it by using `nginx:alpine`.

Comment: can confirm that using the alpine flavour allows for bcrypt passwords

Answer (score 6):

Do you want a MORE secure password hash with nginx basic_auth? Do this:

```sh
echo "username:"$(mkpasswd -m sha-512) >> .htpasswd
```

SHA-512 is not considered nearly as good as bcrypt, but it's the best nginx supports at the moment.

Comment: Just `htpasswd -5` will generate that for you.

Comment: htpasswd: illegal option -- 5

Comment: Interesting, must be version-specific.

Answer (score 3):

I will just stick the htpassword file under "/etc/nginx" myself.
Assuming it is named `htcontrol`, then ...

`sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/htcontrol calvin`

Follow the prompt for the password and the file will be in the correct place.

```
location / {
    ...

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htcontrol;
}
```

or `auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htcontrol;` but the first variant works for me

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem - after checking log as suggested by @Drazen Urch I've discovered that the file had `root:root` permissions - after changing to `forge:forge` (I'm using Forge with Digital Ocean) - the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just use correct [RFC 2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#section-5.3) syntax:

```
passwordvalue          = schemeprefix encryptedpassword
schemeprefix           = "{" scheme "}"
scheme                 = "crypt" / "md5" / "sha" / altscheme
altscheme              = "x-" keystring
encryptedpassword      = encrypted password
```

For example: sha1 for `helloworld` for `admin` will be

- `admin:{SHA}at+xg6SiyUovktq1redipHiJpaE=`

I had same error cause i wrote `{SHA1}` what against RFC syntax. When i fixed it - all worked like a charm. `{sha}` will not work too. Only correct `{SHA}`.

Answer (score 1):

First, check out your nginx error logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

In my case, I found the error:

```
[crit] 18901#18901: *6847 open() "/root/temp/.htpasswd" failed (13: Permission denied),
```

The `/root/temp` directory is one of my test directories, and cannot be read by nginx. After change it to `/etc/apache2/` (follow the official guide https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) everything works fine.

===

After executing the `ps` command we can see the nginx worker process maintained by the user `www-data`, I had tried to `chown www-data:www-data /root/temp` to make sure `www-data` can access this file, but it still not working. To be honest, I don't have a very deep understanding on Linux File Permissions, so I change it to `/etc/apache2/` to fix this in the end. And after a test, you can put the `.htpasswd` file in other directories which in `/etc` (like `/etc/nginx`).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same problem while setting up authentication for kibana. Here is the error in my /var/log/nginx/error.log file

> 2020/04/13 13:43:08 [crit] 49662#49662: *152 crypt_r() failed (22:
>   Invalid argument), client: 157.42.72.240, server: 168.61.168.150,
>   request: “GET / HTTP/1.1”, host: “168.61.168.150”

I resolved this issue by adding authentication using this.

```
sudo sh -c "echo -n 'kibanaadmin:' >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users"
sudo sh -c "openssl passwd -apr1 >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users"
```

You can refer this post if you are trying to setup kibana and got this issue.

https://medium.com/@shubham.singh98/log-monitoring-with-elk-stack-c5de72f0a822?postPublishedType=repub

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using plain text password by `-p` flag, and coincidentally my password start with `$` character.
So I updated my password and thus the error was gone.

NB: Other people answer helped me a lot to figure out my problem. I am posting my solution here if anyone stuck in a rare case like me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had my `auth_basic` setup protecting an nginx location that was served by a `proxy_pass` configuration.

The configured `proxy_pass` location wasn't returning a successful HTTP200 response, which caused nginx to respond with an Internal Server Error after I had entered the correct username and password.

If you have a similar setup, ensure that the `proxy_pass` location protected by `auth_basic` is returning an HTTP200 response after you rule out username/password issues.