# How to generate a valid password hash for a .htpasswd file in Terraform?

Tags: openssl, terraform, bcrypt, .htpasswd, md5sum

How to generate a valid password hash for a given password for a .htpasswd file in Terraform?

Meaning: How to execute the following command using a Terraform plugin/ module:

```
echo "MYUSERNAME:$( openssl passwd -apr1 MYPASSWORD )" > .htpasswd
```

Other algorithms would also be ok. The line has just to be accepted for basic auth.

What doesn't work:

- [bcrypt function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/bcrypt.html)

  - [See this Stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833583/nginx-gives-an-internal-server-error-500-after-i-have-configured-basic-auth)
- [md5 function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/md5.html)

  - Executes hashing only once. The "apr1" function executes this hashing 1000 times. Thus => incompatible.

I just don't want to rely on tools (i.e. htpasswd or openssl) to be installed locally. This would require the "local-exec" provisioner. But I think there is no way around...

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the below locally and it works with terraform 0.12

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 55
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}


resource "local_file" "foo" {
    content     = random_password.password.result
    filename = "${path.module}/.htpasswd"
}
```

You will need the following providers:

```
 * provider.local: version = "~> 1.4"
 * provider.random: version = "~> 2.2"
```

When a terraform apply is run, it generates the following file:

```
.htpassword
```

Here's an example of the password it generates in the above htpassword file

```
MlqXMGCYUpij0Du8ycWoVLkJurbP822R26HB
```

---

If you need to hash a specific password then you can do something like this:

```
variable "bcrypt-password" {
  default = "MyPassword"
}

output "bcrypt" {
  value = "${bcrypt(var.bcrypt-password,6)}"
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to generate a password with Terraform and use it in `.htpasswd`. It took a bit of effort, but it comes down to the following:

- Use `bcrypt`
- Ensure that you're using an [alpine version of Nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/29#issuecomment-194817391) (tested with `nginx:alpine` on 27th of October 2020), as Nginx uses any library that is available on the system (alpine has `bcrypt`)

Example (make sure to use a Kubernetes secret instead of a Config Map in production):

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 30
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map" "htpasswd_config_map" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-htpasswd"
  }
  data = {
    ".htpasswd" = <<EOF
myusername:${bcrypt(random_password.password.result)}
EOF
  }
}
```

In case you're also using Kubernetes, you can mount this in the Nginx pod.

*Important remark*: I was testing different approaches for passwords, and I had to delete all site data in my browser when trying to access the Nginx deployment. It kept rejecting the password until I opened an incognito window / wiped the site data.

Comment: Using `<<-EOF` would allow you to keep proper indentation there.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that one yet, thanks :)

Comment: I would advise to use a `kubernetes_secret` instead of `kubernetes_config_map` for secret values.

Comment: Definitely @sshow, this is merely an example, but good point.

Comment: The `bcrypt()` function generates random salt and uses it in creating the hash, so its result is different every time Terraform runs, even with the same input. Because of this, this example will update the `ConfigMap` in k8s every single time Terraform is run. For the specific case of a `ConfigMap` it may be relatively harmless but in other cases (e.g. setting the root password of a server) it may result in reboots/downtime.

Comment: I added this so that data does not change each time. 

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      data
    ]
  }
```

Comment: random_password also supports `.bcrypt_hash` directly: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/password#bcrypt_hash. Makes it much easier, no need to lifecycle ignore etc.