# phpmyadmin 500 Internal Server Error after enabling authentication gateway

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm running it on NGINX server, it worked fine untill I enabled authentication gateway.
I generated encrypted passsword using `openssl passwd` and added /etc/nginx/pma_pass file with user: encryptedPassword line. Also I added location block inside server block in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. It looks like this

```
location /urlpath { 
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
}
```

I get authentication prompt followed by 500 no matter what I put in it. What could be the problem here ?

Here's my entire server block:

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.domain domain ipaddress;

        location ^~ /urlpath {
                auth_basic "Admin Login";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                }
        }

  
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/path; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/path; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/path; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/path; 

}
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log last entry

```
2020/07/04 10:57:44 [crit] 18699#18699: *530 crypt_r() failed (22: Invalid argument), client: 82.208.215.144, server: www.whatevs.info, request: "GET /path_phpadmin_is_located_at/ HTTP/1.1", host: "domain"
```

Comment: You need to duplicate all other directives from your root `location / { ... }` block, possibly including the nested `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block and use `location ^~ /urlpath { ... }` for this one.

Comment: @IvanShatsky same result all over again, is this what you had in mind ?                                               location  ^~ /urlpath {
                auth_basic "Admin Login";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                }
        }

Comment: Damn, why no code formatting for comments ...

Comment: Can you update your question with your full `server` block? You can omit private info such as domain name, certificates path etc.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Updated question w/ server block

Comment: You are trying to protect some app (looks like it is phpMyAdmin) with additional HTTP basic auth, yes? Is it physically located in `/var/www/html/urlpath` directory? What are the last lines of your nginx error log when you get a 500 error?

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes, I enabled auth for phpmyadmin. /var/www/html contains symbolic link pointing to /usr/share/phpmyadmin, and I renamed it so that phpmyadmin can not be accessed at obvious domain/phpmyadmin path. I updated question w/ last entry from /var/log/ngnix/error.log

Comment: Looks like nginx doesn't like your `pma_pass` file contents (or to be more precise its a system libc library who doesn't like it). There should be no spaces in `user:password` line. You can also try to force an encryption algorithm with `openssl passwd -crypt` (system default) or `openssl passwd -apr1` (apache default).

Comment: Additionally take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833583/nginx-gives-an-internal-server-error-500-after-i-have-configured-basic-auth) Q/A.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I modified pma_pass so it's user:password and now it goes straight to phpmyadmin without auth prompt - as if I neved enabled it ! Gonna take a look at that post you linked, thanks for the effort brother.

Comment: Maybe your login/password somehow got cached with your browser? Try to login from the incognito window.

Comment: @IvanShatsky it worked !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to hear, summarized all of this as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up all the discussion in the comments, the solution is

- such a protected location should have its own nested PHP handler and use `^~` location modifier (to aviod the requests like `/urlpath/index.php` to be captured by `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` location below):

  ```
  location ^~ /urlpath {
      auth_basic "Admin Login";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      }
  }
  ```
- password file should contain the lines in form of `<user_name>:<hashed_password>` and should not contain any extra spaces within such a line.